# Pushing new FormGroup into FormArray marks dynamic FormGroup as invalid

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material-6

I'm not sure if this is a bug, almost 90% certain it's not, but I want to know the logic behind something like this occuring.

I have a component, where let's say I'm initializing a FormGroup on the initialization of the component.

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  form!: FormGroup;
  foos!: FormArray;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      foos: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  createFoo(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      details: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  addFoo(): void {
    this.foos = this.form.get('foos') as FormArray;
    this.foos.push(this.createFoo());
  }
}
```

Let's say the `addFoo()` function gets called on a button click (which is how it is in my current application). Why is the newly pushed `FormGroup` marked as `pristine` but `invalid`? Even if there is a solid reason for this, shouldn't one assume that if we're dynamically generating a new `FormGroup` with validators, it should be considered valid upon creation or `push`? Is there a way around this? I don't want to have my users click a button to generate a new group of fields to fill out that are already marked invalid when they haven't done anything to those fields themselves. Is this a bug? I don't feel like my implementation is incorrect since I've followed the Angular Material documentation for this. I've tried setting the `Validators.required` manually after the new `foo` is pushed into the `FormArray` but this yields the same result.

Any opinions and/or tips?

Comment: I'm also having the same trouble here, but I don't want to add value or remove the validators, any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you question here is an answer.

On initial state your `this.form` is valid

then createFoo() creates a `formGroup` which is invalid due empty value provided with required validator.

When you try to push invalid `formGroup` to a valid formGroup Array then `this.form` get invalid.

If you want valid on push try to add value or remove the required validator

For REF:

FormBuilder creates the Group with formControl like this

```
new FormControl(value: any, validator: Validators);
```

Comment: This wasn't the exact answer I was looking for but helped me get to a solution. I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @DanielPark what was your solution? Have the very same problem and dont feel like adding a complete valid initial value.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation where whenever I added a new formGroup to my formArray its validations would get triggered even though they were untouched & pristine. Turns out if you use a button to dynamically add formGroups it will default the action to a submit event, triggering validations to run if you do not specify the button type.

Adding type="button" resolved the issue

REF: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514431/reactive-form-array-avoid-validation-error-when-push-new-elements#:~:text=Reactive%20Form%20Array%20%2D%20Avoid%20Validation%20Error%20when%20push%20new%20elements,-angular%20angular%2Dreactive&text=When%20I%20push%20new%20elements,I%20create%20the%20new%20FormGroup%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514431/reactive-form-array-avoid-validation-error-when-push-new-elements#:%7E:text=Reactive%20Form%20Array%20%2D%20Avoid%20Validation%20Error%20when%20push%20new%20elements,-angular%20angular%2Dreactive&text=When%20I%20push%20new%20elements,I%20create%20the%20new%20FormGroup%20).