# Add a row dynamically : Angular Reactive-Form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to add row dynamically when I click the `button`. I'm using reactive-form for this.
[image: Here's what I'm talking about]

here is my html code

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class='tableHeader'>
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                <td fxFlex="22" class="pr-4">Name</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Price</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Loan Term</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Quantity</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Deposit</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Total</td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr [formGroup]="loanProductForm">
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                <td fxFlex="22">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Product </mat-label>
                        <mat-select formControlName="productId" required>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let product of productList" [value]="product.productId">
                                {{product.name}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Price </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' matInput formControlName="price" name="" id="" placeholder="Price" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Loan Term </mat-label>
                        <mat-select formControlName="loanTermId" required>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let loanTerm of loanTermList" [value]="loanTerm.loanTermId">
                                {{loanTerm.numberOfMonths}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Quantity </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' formControlName="quantity" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Quantity" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Deposit </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' formControlName="deposit" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Deposit" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Total </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' formControlName="total" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Total" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>

            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td fxFlex="10">
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                    <button mat-stroked-button class='addBtn btn-style-2' fxFlex='100' (click)='addTableRow()'>Add
                        <mat-icon matSuffix>add_box</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is how I'm trying in my `ts` file

```
   this.loanProductForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      productId: ['', Validators.required],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      loanTermId: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: ['', Validators.required],
      deposit: ['', Validators.required],
      total: ['', Validators.required],
    })


addTableRow() {
    this.newRow = { productId: '', price: '', loanTermId: '', quantity: '', deposit: '', total: '' };
    // this.tableRows.push(this.newRow)
  }
```

but the code won't let me use `push` method on this form

Comment: I guess you mean reactive-form ?

Comment: yes exactly, sorry I typo, I'm just correcting it

Comment: Add another line of form or add the form value as a line?

Comment: I mean the add button will insert a new row below

Comment: new row of values or a new row of inputs?

Comment: You should use FormArray , https://medium.com/@mustafakunwa/reactive-form-in-angular-with-formarray-2595e5ee1d31

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Form Array in this case.

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usshu2?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

.ts

```
this.loanProductForm = this.fb.group({
  products: this.fb.array([
    this.addProductFormGroup()
  ])
});

 addProductFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      productId: ['', Validators.required],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      loanTermId: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: ['', Validators.required],
      deposit: ['', Validators.required],
      total: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

addProductButtonClick(): void {
   (<FormArray>this.loanProductForm.get('products')).push(this.addProductFormGroup());
}
```

.html

```
 <button type="button" (click)="addProductButtonClick()">
          Add Product
 </button>
```

Comment: I'm getting error on your second code snippet.
Cannot find name `addProductFormGroup`
where should I write this code.
I wrote it just just under the the formBuilder group as in your

Comment: It is a separate function

Comment: Sorry, my code complied and executed successfully but its not working, i.e. not adding row on click event. Nor do it is producing any error on console

Comment: Check the demo I shared

Comment: I tried to create a stackblitz demo, but was getting error don't know why.
you demo is working perfectly, let me make this work in mine too

Comment: @Lint Take the approach from here and inplement in your project, look at the html too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202719/discussion-between-lint-and-adrita-sharma).

Comment: its working now, but there's a little trouble and that as as I click the add button, the new row instantly becomes red (like that in case of form invalid) to avoid that problem

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514431/reactive-form-array-avoid-validation-error-when-push-new-elements

Comment: And kindly upvote and accept the answer if it was useful

Comment: I've read that question, but the demo link to stackblitz is broken, so can you please explain to me in simple words what should I do to avoid that behavior in my problem

Comment: 1st of all , show the invalid class only when the input is touched. If it doesn't work, make the newly added item pristine

Comment: I'm confused yet, can you write a code snippet.
I shall be extremely thankful to you for this regard

Comment: *ngIf="product.get('productId').errors?.required &&
                  product.get('productId').touched"

Comment: I have added it in the demo

Comment: I'm still getting an error look in the image
https://imgur.com/GmHL73V

Comment: I have shown how to do it, if a have to fix your code, you have to share your code in stackbiltz

Answer (score 3):

I think this should help you:

https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Comment: this link is broken

Comment: Sorry. Repaired

Answer (score 1):

You need to use form array instead of form group :

ts

```
  ...

       this.loanProductForm = this._formBuilder.group(
           loanProductArray : this._formBuilder.array([this.buildGroup()])
    ) ;


    get loanProductArray(){
      return this.loanProductForm.get('loanProductArray ') as FormArray ;
    }

    buildGroup(){
    return    this.loanProductForm = this._formBuilder.group({
          productId: ['', Validators.required],
          price: ['', Validators.required],
          loanTermId: ['', Validators.required],
          quantity: ['', Validators.required],
          deposit: ['', Validators.required],
          total: ['', Validators.required],
        })
    }

addTableRow() {
   this.loanProductArray.push(this.buildGroup()) ;
  }
```

html

```
    ...

 <tbody [formGroup]="loanProductForm">
   <ng-container formArrayName="loanProductArray">
        <tr *ngFor="let line of loanProductArray.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                <td fxFlex="22">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Product </mat-label>
                        <mat-select formControlName="productId" required>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let product of productList" [value]="product.productId">
                                {{product.name}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Price </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' matInput formControlName="price" name="" id="" placeholder="Price" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Loan Term </mat-label>
                        <mat-select formControlName="loanTermId" required>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let loanTerm of loanTermList" [value]="loanTerm.loanTermId">
                                {{loanTerm.numberOfMonths}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Quantity </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' formControlName="quantity" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Quantity" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Deposit </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' formControlName="deposit" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Deposit" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Total </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' formControlName="total" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Total" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>

            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td fxFlex="10">
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                    <button mat-stroked-button class='addBtn btn-style-2' fxFlex='100' (click)='addTableRow()'>Add
                        <mat-icon matSuffix>add_box</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</<ng-container>
    </tbody>
```